# What does this unix command means?

Tags: bash, .htaccess, unix, ssh, capistrano

I am using Capistrano 3 in order to deploy my app. Some of the commands that Capistrano executes failed.
Here are two of them:

```
DEBUG [ca206483] Running /usr/bin/env [ -L /home1/webdevea/public_html/staging/releases/20141204173857/.htaccess ] on staging.myhousehold.co
DEBUG [ca206483] Command: [ -L /home1/webdevea/public_html/staging/releases/20141204173857/.htaccess ]
DEBUG [ca206483] Finished in 3.276 seconds with exit status 1 (failed).
DEBUG [cf9a9b43] Running /usr/bin/env [ -f /home1/webdevea/public_html/staging/releases/20141204173857/.htaccess ] on staging.myhousehold.co
DEBUG [cf9a9b43] Command: [ -f /home1/webdevea/public_html/staging/releases/20141204173857/.htaccess ]
DEBUG [cf9a9b43] Finished in 3.072 seconds with exit status 1 (failed).
```

What exactly the commands `/usr/bin/env [ -L /home1/webdevea/public_html/staging/releases/20141204173857/.htaccess ]` and `/usr/bin/env [ -f /home1/webdevea/public_html/staging/releases/20141204173857/.htaccess ]` does?

Are those commands related to ssh? bash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `env`<sup>[1](http://linux.die.net/man/1/env)</sup>

> env - run a program in a modified environment

For `[`/`test`<sup>[1](http://linux.die.net/man/1/test)</sup>

> test - check file types and compare values
>
> -f FILE
>
> FILE exists and is a regular file
>
> -L FILE
>
> FILE exists and is a symbolic link (same as -h)